# Improve performance with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, left-join

I have a mysql query that has 5 or 6 LEFT JOINS. As expected, this is pretty slow. Considering that I'm only expecting ~100 results, might it make more sense for me to run lots of separate sql queries and manually stitch them together. I'm guessing that it's taking a long time because of the huge table that is created with multiple left joins. Is that right?

I'm doing this in Rails 3. I know that creating active records is expensive, but I'm figuring it may be faster than having so many LEFT JOINS. I know very little about how the database works under the hood. Would really appreciate any insights.

---

Edit: Here's the actual query and table schemas

Query

> SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` LEFT JOIN
>   `person_organization_relationships` ON
>   `person_organization_relationships`.person_id = `people`.id AND
>   `person_organization_relationships`.stop_person IS NULL LEFT JOIN
>   `person_redirect_relationships` AS r_from_others ON
>   r_from_others.parent_id = `people`.id AND r_from_others.stop_person IS
>   NULL LEFT JOIN `person_redirect_relationships` AS r_to_others ON
>   r_to_others.child_id = `people`.id AND r_to_others.stop_person IS NULL
>   LEFT JOIN `person_organization_relationships` AS r_p_check ON
>   r_p_check.person_id = r_from_others.child_id AND r_p_check.stop_person
>   IS NULL LEFT JOIN `organization_redirect_relationships` AS r_o_check
>   ON r_o_check.child_id =
>   `person_organization_relationships`.organization_id AND
>   r_o_check.stop_organization IS NULL LEFT JOIN
>   `person_organization_relationships` AS rr_p_check ON
>   rr_p_check.person_id = r_from_others.child_id AND
>   rr_p_check.stop_person IS NULL LEFT JOIN
>   `organization_redirect_relationships` AS rr_o_check ON
>   rr_p_check.organization_id = rr_o_check.child_id AND
>   rr_o_check.stop_organization IS NULL WHERE
>   (((`person_organization_relationships`.organization_id = 1 OR
>   r_o_check.parent_id = 1) AND r_to_others.parent_id IS NULL) OR
>   (r_p_check.organization_id = 1 OR rr_o_check.parent_id = 1)) GROUP BY
>   `people`.id

Table schema:

```
  create_table "people", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "delta",             :default => true, :null => false
  end


  create_table "person_organization_relationships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "person_id"
    t.integer  "organization_id"
    t.integer  "start_person"
    t.integer  "stop_person"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "person_organization_relationships", ["organization_id"], :name => "index_person_organization_relationships_on_organization_id"
  add_index "person_organization_relationships", ["person_id"], :name => "index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id"
  add_index "person_organization_relationships", ["start_person"], :name => "index_person_organization_relationships_on_start_person"
  add_index "person_organization_relationships", ["stop_person"], :name => "index_person_organization_relationships_on_stop_person"

  create_table "person_redirect_relationships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "child_id"
    t.integer  "start_person"
    t.integer  "stop_person"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "person_redirect_relationships", ["child_id"], :name => "index_person_redirect_relationships_on_child_id"
  add_index "person_redirect_relationships", ["parent_id"], :name => "index_person_redirect_relationships_on_parent_id"
  add_index "person_redirect_relationships", ["start_person"], :name => "index_person_redirect_relationships_on_start_person"
  add_index "person_redirect_relationships", ["stop_person"], :name => "index_person_redirect_relationships_on_stop_person"


  create_table "organization_redirect_relationships", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "child_id"
    t.integer  "start_organization"
    t.integer  "stop_organization"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "organization_redirect_relationships", ["child_id"], :name => "index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_child_id"
  add_index "organization_redirect_relationships", ["parent_id"], :name => "index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_parent_id"
  add_index "organization_redirect_relationships", ["start_organization"], :name => "index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_start_organization"
  add_index "organization_redirect_relationships", ["stop_organization"], :name => "index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_stop_organization"
```

---

This query yielded no results.

> +----+-------------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+ | id | select_type | table                             | type   |
>   possible_keys
>   | key                                                   | key_len |
>   ref
>   | rows | Extra                           |
>   +----+-------------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+ |  1 | SIMPLE      | person_details                    | ALL    |
>   index_person_details_on_current_p_id
>   | NULL                                                  | NULL    |
>   NULL
>   | 4938 | Using temporary; Using filesort | |  1 | SIMPLE      | people
>   | eq_ref | PRIMARY
>   | PRIMARY                                               | 4       |
>   knolcano_development.person_details.current_p_id
>   |    1 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   person_organization_relationships | ref    |
>   index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id,index_person_organization_relationships_on_stop_person
>   | index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id  | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.person_details.current_p_id
>   |    1 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   r_from_others                     | ref    |
>   index_person_redirect_relationships_on_parent_id,index_person_redirect_relationships_on_stop_person
>   | index_person_redirect_relationships_on_stop_person    | 5       |
>   const
>   |    3 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   r_to_others                       | ref    |
>   index_person_redirect_relationships_on_child_id,index_person_redirect_relationships_on_stop_person
>   | index_person_redirect_relationships_on_child_id       | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.people.id
>   |    2 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   r_p_check                         | ref    |
>   index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id,index_person_organization_relationships_on_stop_person
>   | index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id  | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.r_from_others.child_id
>   |    1 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   r_o_check                         | ref    |
>   index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_child_id,index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_stop_organization
>   | index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_child_id | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.person_organization_relationships.organization_id
>   |    1 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   rr_p_check                        | ref    |
>   index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id,index_person_organization_relationships_on_stop_person
>   | index_person_organization_relationships_on_person_id  | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.r_from_others.child_id
>   |    1 |                                 | |  1 | SIMPLE      |
>   rr_o_check                        | ref    |
>   index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_child_id,index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_stop_organization
>   | index_organization_redirect_relationships_on_child_id | 5       |
>   knolcano_development.rr_p_check.organization_id
>   |    1 | Using where                     |
>   +----+-------------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+ 9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

But when I ran the query it took 0.14 sec. Is that a long period of time? I'm trying to figure out if I have good queries before I implement memcached.

Comment: The actual query and EXPLAIN output would be helpful bits of information.

Comment: I agree with @JoeStefanelli. Show us the query + result of `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 7):

So many JOINs may be a very bad idea, but you should show your query first.

First of all, indexes are required to speed up the query. If you do not have any, you probably should create some (depending on the query you perform).

And if you do multiple LEFT JOINs, then you could (probably) separate them into different queries and this should make the application work a lot faster.

You can refer to the [MySQL's documentation on optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html), specifically [LEFT JOIN optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html) and [optimization using indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html). This may give you additional details.

Comment: Good answer, I just want to emphasize that bad use of indexes is the most likely cause of bad performance in these type of scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a number of reasons for this.  Poor query performance, bad indexes, and so on.  The explain, query, and probably even create table statements for the tables in question would go a very long way to helping come to an answer.

Most of the time when I see this kind of thing, though, it is a matter of poor indexes.